# cast function is extremely memory consuming, how to handle it?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregation

I have a table looks like:

```
date    item_id    store_id   sale_num
1/1/15    33         1          10
1/1/15    33         2          12
1/1/15    33         3          15
1/1/15    44         1          54
1/1/15    44         3          66 
1/2/15    33         1          14
....
```

I want to cast the table, in order to put store_id into multiple columns, and value is the sale_num. The table should be like:

```
date    item_id   store1   store2   store3  
1/1/15   33         10       12       15
1/1/15   44         54       NA       66
1/2/15   33         14       NA       NA
......
```

When I do this using cast function in a small scale, 1000 rows in original table, there is no problem.

However, the original table has 38,000,000 rows and comsumes 1.5 GB memory in R. 
When I use cast function, the function cost around 34 GB memory, and it runs endlessly.

What is the problem of it? Is there any alternative way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the `dcast` from `data.table`.  It should be more efficient than the `cast` from `reshape`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`) and then use `dcast`.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), date+item_id~ paste0("store", 
              store_id), value.var="sale_num")
#      date item_id store1 store2 store3
#1: 1/1/15      33     10     12     15
#2: 1/1/15      44     54     NA     66
#3: 1/2/15      33     14     NA     NA
```